# Vietnam e-visa photo requirements

Tags: visas, vietnam, photography

I started applying for a Vietnam e-visa and it requires "foreigners' passport data page image and photograph (straight looking without glasses)". The example images given are: the data page, and a photograph that matches the one on the data page exactly:

[image]

It's unclear whether the photograph should be the same exact photo found in the passport. It wouldn't be a problem for me to include the exact photo except I am wearing glasses in that photo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From personal experience, I can tell you that as long as the photo you include conforms to the specifications, it doesn't have to be the very photo you provided for your passport. Indeed, in at least one of my passports, the photo was taken directly by the consulate, and I don't have it. It'd be difficult for me to provide the exact same photo!